# Difficulty understanding classes

Tags: java, class

I am having a difficult time understanding how classes work and cant figure out how to take my currentToken make it into a word then use the word class to scramble it or not then return the word either scrambled or not into a println.

Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Readability
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner doc = new Scanner( new File("README.txt"));//imports README.txt
        System.out.println(tokens);
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> punctuation(Scanner doc){//creates new method called punctuation 
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList();//creates new arraylist called tokens
        while (doc.hasNext()){//loops through README.txt to find all punctuation that needs to be fixed
            String currentToken = doc.nextLine();//assigns the character that is being read as currentToken
            Word wordObject = new Word(currentToken);
            wordObject.toString();
            if (currentToken.length()>0){//loop that converts all currentTokens to lowerCase and adds currentToken to token
                tokens.add(currentToken);
            }
        }
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Word Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Word{
    String word;
    public Word(String w){
        word=w;
    }
    public String toString(){
        if (word.length()<6) {
            return word;
        }
        else {
            String first = word.substring(0,2);
            int length = word.length();
            String middle = word.substring(2,length-2);
            ArrayList<String> scrambled = new ArrayList<String>();
            scrambled.add(middle);
            Collections.shuffle(scrambled);
            String last = word.substring(length-2);
            return first+scrambled+last;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with your program (which one)?

Comment: @Henry My println is giving me an error: Cannot find symbol: variable tokens. I also am not able to tell if my current tokens are being read by the word class and scrambled at all and if those are even going to my main method in my main class.

Comment: return first+scrambled+last; this will lead to issues, since scrambled isn't a String you are concatenating

Comment: @ValentinCarnu `punctuation` method is static. no need to instatiate `Readability`

Comment: @ValentinCarnu I didn't mention that at all. why on earth would a toString method return a List? Change the returntype, and you'll get compilation issues

Comment: @ValentinCarnu how would I create an instance of Readability if I need everything in Word to be a string would that cause a bunch of errors?

Comment: @Stultuske how would I use Collections.scramble without it being an ArrayList? I am honestly so confused.

Comment: @ic0n I have never said that you can't use a list for that, I only said that "String" + anArrayList + "String" will not give "StringanArrayListString". You need to add the contents of the list, not the list itself as Strings to concatenate

Comment: @Stultuske I've miss read your comment, after you pointed out I've removed my comments and added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but maybe it helps

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Readability {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner doc = new Scanner(new File("README.txt"));//imports README.txt
        List<String> tokens = Readability.punctuation(doc);
        tokens.stream().forEach(token -> System.out.println(token));
    }

    public static List<String> punctuation(Scanner doc) {//creates new method called punctuation
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList();//creates new arraylist called tokens
        while (doc.hasNext()) {//loops through README.txt to find all punctuation that needs to be fixed
            String currentToken = doc.nextLine();//assigns the character that is being read as currentToken
            Word wordObject = new Word(currentToken);
            if (currentToken.length() > 0) {//loop that converts all currentTokens to lowerCase and adds currentToken to token
                tokens.add(wordObject.scramble());
            }
        }
        return tokens;
    }
}

class Word {

    private String word;

    public Word(String w) {
        word = w;
    }

    public String scramble() {
        if (word.length() < 6) {
            return word;
        } else {
            String first = word.substring(0, 2);
            int length = word.length();
            String middle = word.substring(2, length - 2);
            List<String> scrambled = new ArrayList<String>();
            scrambled.add(middle);
            Collections.shuffle(scrambled);
            String scrambledWord = scrambled.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            String last = word.substring(length - 2);
            return first + scrambledWord + last;
        }
    }
}
```